# How can customize Customer account activation email template via shopify api ?

Tags: templates, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I'm creating a private app for a customer that are using Shopify as the shopping platform.

At the moment, I'm creating the customers via. the Shopify API (http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer).

It's working perfectly, but i want to customize the email templates for activation account to add an email and password.

Please how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need custom control over the account activation email you can create the customer records with `send_email_welcome : false` and then use the [account_activation_url API call](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#account_activation_url) to create an account activation url which you could embed in your own fully custom email message.

Why would you want to send a password though? You have no idea whether or not the customer receives email securely and the activation link lets them reset the password anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you click settings -> notifications in the shop, you'll notice you can edit these outgoing email templates to customers. That is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this app : ["Emailchekr - customer account verification"](https://apps.shopify.com/customer-account-verification)

As a fellow Shopify merchant, we know how crucial email marketing is for your business.
That's why we're thrilled to introduce you to “EmailCheckr”, the ultimate Shopify app for email validation.

“EmailCheckr” helps merchants to ensure that the customer’s email address is valid and that they are who they say they are.
With email verification, businesses can increase their security and protect their customers’ data from malicious activities.
Email verification also helps businesses maintain accurate records of customer information, which can be used for marketing purposes or to improve customer service.

Features :

- Account activation emails are sent to customers to verify their emails.
- Verify customer emails to protect your business.
- It keeps your email lists fresh by eliminating fake customer account signups.